# Printing pseudo variables in Yacc

Tags: bison, yacc

Helo.

I'm learning `yacc` and I'm having some problems understanding something.

This is part of my `.y` file:

```
statement:  statement expression '\n'   {$$=insert_expression_list($1, $2); printf("1\n");}
        | expression    '\n'    {$$=insert_expression_list(NULL, $1); myprogram=$$; printf("1.1\n");}
        ;

expression: infix_expression    {$$=insert_i_expression($1); printf("2\n");}
        | unary_expression  {$$=insert_u_expression($1);}
        | NUMBER        {$$=insert_NUMBER($1); printf("test %d\n", $1); }
        ;       

infix_expression: expression '+' expression {printf("3 %d + %d\n", $1, $3); $$=insert_infix_expression($1, is_PLUS, $3);}
        | expression '-' expression {$$=insert_infix_expression($1, is_MINUS, $3);}
        ;

unary_expression: '-' expression    %prec UMINUS    {$$=insert_unary_expression($2);}
            ;
```

As you can see I'm trying to print some "debug" information.
This is the output of a file containing `1+2+5`.

```
test 1
test 2
3 -2147318816 + -2147318800
2
test 5
3 -2147069008 + -2147068992
2
1.1
```

The problem is at `infix_expression: expression '+' expression {printf("3 %d + %d\n", $1, $3);`
Isn't this the correct way to print those values? in `NUMBER        {$$=insert_NUMBER($1); printf("test %d\n", $1); }` the value is printed as I expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the line `3 -2147318816 + -2147318800`, the values `-2147318816` and `-2147318800` are the values assigned to `$$` in the `expression: NUMBER` rule -- the values returned by your `insert_NUMBER` function.  I'm guessing that these are actually pointers that you are printing as integers.  Normally I would expect your compiler to give you a message about assigning a pointer to an integer without a cast, but if you compile without warnings it might not.

Normally if you want to use different types for the values in yacc/bison (rather than just having everything be an `int` -- the default), you need a `%union` declaration to define all the different possible semantic value types, and you need to specify which union field to use for all tokens and nonterminals with appropriate `%token` and `%type` declarations.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to do that.